# "without needing to <verb> + ..." vs "without the need of <verb + ing> + ..."

Tags: phrases, grammaticality

I don't see which one is fits best:

> it is awesome because you can do it **without needing to send** e-mails

or

> it is awesome because you can do it **without the need of sending** e-mails

Also, are both correct or just one (or none...)?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, I think, but I'd reject both and use "... you can do it without sending e-mails".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one is correct.  The second one can be corrected as:

> It is awesome because you can do it without the need *to send* emails.

Comment: A gerundophile could also say *…without the need for sending e-mails*.

Comment: @choster of course!  I'm so embarrassed.  (._.)

Comment: _need of sending_ is OK, too.

Comment: My new word of the day: gerundophile. I am loving it.

Comment: @John Lawler - Why are "need of sending" and "need to send" both correct?

Comment: Because you can use either _of_ or _for_ with a gerund clause after the noun need, **or** you can use an infinitive clause with _to_.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two samples where "without the need of", not "to", is used:

- [Apple's AirPlay May Soon Work Without The Need Of A Wifi Network](http://www.complex.com/tech/2012/08/apples-airplay-may-soon-work-without-the-need-of-a-wifi-network)
- 

> TAX REFUNDS: Income Tax refunds will be devoted each year, as periodic payments, to the plan’s funding until plan completion. The tender of such payments shall deem the plan modified by such amount, increasing the base thereby without the need of further notice, hearing or Court order. In [sic] need be for the use by debtor(s) of a portion of such refund, debtor(s) shall seek Court’s authorization prior to any use of funds.
>   — [Source](http://www.bap1.uscourts.gov/cgi-bin/bpgetopn.pl?OPINION=11-074P)
>   
>   I guess it's a matter of whether you use a verb or a noun after the phrase:

- *without the need to* + verb
- *without the need for* + noun